# Pip managed python extending distribution packaged modules

Tags: python, environment-variables, pip

I am looking for recommendations on extending the python library managed by my arbitrary distribution with packages available via PPI.

Basically I have been working with a distro managed installation at `/usr`, and I wish to have the option of extending that distro at `/usr/local` with `pip`, while maintaining the option for each user to have installations that inherit `/usr` -> `/usr/local` -> `~/.local/python` (or whatever dir they setup with virtualenv).

I am open to solutions that don't involve virtualenv in the `/usr/local` step.

Comment: `pip install --user <package>`.

Comment: " arbitrary distribution"? I don't follow. Are you using multiple distributions, or do you just want a general answer for some reason? In any case, for Debian/Ubuntu it is now actually quite easy to make binary Debian packages for many Python libraries as long as you are not too fussed about dotting the i's and crossing the t's.